# Treat a single integer value as a range in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, integer, range, nsrange

I need to validate the length of a string. The allowed values for the character count are:

- 6 – 9 characters
- 12 characters
- 15 characters

All strings with a different character count are invalid. Thus, I would like to create a Swift function that accepts a number of ranges and evaluates the string:

```
extension String {

    func evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: Range<Int>...) -> Bool {
        // Implementation
    }

}
```

Now I can call the function for a single `Int` range:

```
"Live long and prosper".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: 6..<10)
```

and multiple `Int` ranges:

```
"Live long and prosper".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: 6..<10, 15..<20)
```

But I cannot call the function with single, isolated integer values:

```
"Live long and prosper".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: 6..<10, 12, 15)
```

because `12` and `15` are typed as `Int` and not as `Range<Int>`.

> **Swift compile error:** Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Range'

**Is there a way to treat a single Integer as a `Range` in Swift, like casting it automatically to `Range<Int>`?**

(After all `5` is equivalent to `5..<6`, so mathematically speaking `5` is a range as well.)

Comment: An alternative would be to pass an argument of type `IndexSet`.

Comment: You mean something like `evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: IndexSet(6..<10), IndexSet(12, 15))`? Or is there a neater solution with `IndexSet` that allows a similar syntax as described above?

Comment: @Mischa, Did you even find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with 3 solutions but I don't either of them are as pleasing as would be if the method accepts `Int` or `Range<Int>` but here we go?

1 - You have type safety but have to use some workarounds:

```
extension String {
    func evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [Range<Int>]? = nil) -> Bool {
        if let validCharCounts = validCharacterCounts {
            for validCharCount in validCharCounts {
                if validCharCount.contains(characters.count) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}

extension Int {
    var asRange: Range<Int> {
        return self..<self+1 as Range<Int>
    }
}

"Hello, playground".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [17.asRange, 1, 25, 1..<45]) // true
```

2 - You don't have type safety:

```
extension String {
    func evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        if let validCharCounts = validCharacterCounts {
            for validCharCount in validCharCounts {
                if let range = validCharCount as? Range<Int> {
                    if range.contains(characters.count) {
                        return true
                    }
                } else if let range = validCharCount as? CountableRange<Int> {
                    if range.contains(characters.count) {
                        return true
                    }
                } else if let range = validCharCount as? CountableClosedRange<Int> {
                    if range.contains(characters.count) {
                        return true
                    }
                } else if let int = validCharCount as? Int {
                    if int.asRange.contains(characters.count) {
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected type: \(type(of: validCharCount))")
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}

extension Int {
    var asRange: Range<Int> {
        return self..<self+1 as Range<Int>
    }
}

"Hello, playground".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [12, 1, 4, 6, 14...18]) // true
```

3 - The best so far, but still not perfect solution:

```
extension String {
    func evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [Int]? = nil) -> Bool {
        guard let validCharCounts = validCharacterCounts else {
            return false
        }

        return validCharCounts.contains(characters.count)

    }
}

"Hello, playground".evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: [12, 1, 4, 6] + Array(14...18)) // true
```

Comment: I'm a fanatic when it comes to type safety so I don't appreciate 2 that much. 3 is pretty much what I ended up implementing myself but it doesn't solve the problem either because you still have to treat ranges and single integers differently. Thanks for the ideas though! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Rather than dealing with range semantics, I'm just creating a Set extension with a relevant initializer.

```
extension Set where Element == Int {
    init(with elements: [Int] = [], and ranges: Range<Int>...) {
        var allElements = [elements]
        ranges.forEach {
            allElements.append(Array($0.lowerBound..<$0.upperBound))
        }
        self.init(allElements.joined())
    }
}

let newSet = Set(with: [1, 3, 328], and: 6..<10, 15..<20)
newSet.contains(3)  //true
newSet.contains(4)  //false
newSet.contains(16) //true
```

This allows you to pass only single values, only ranges, or both. The only caveat is the named params separating them.

The `Set` semantics also mean you can create static constants if desired and should be significantly faster as well.

Comment: I've been experimenting with Sets as well. However, this approach introduces a separation between "single integer ranges" and "real" intervals between two different integers. And that's exactly the reason why I asked the question because semantically they are _both_ ranges and so I would like to treat them the same way.

Comment: `evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: 5, 7, 10...20, 25)` is a lot more intuitive than `evaluateLength(validCharacterCounts: 5, 7, 25, validCharacterCountRanges: 10...20)`, for example.

Comment: @Mischa I agree it would be nice to do that, I tried to find a way with protocols but it may not be currently possible with Type safety. (that might change in Swift 4)