# How to add protocol conformance to a generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, range, extension-methods, swift-extensions

I would like to make [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange) conform to the [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringliteral) protocol so that I can create "single integer ranges" (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45620454/2062785)). The goal is to be able to assign integer literals to variables of type `CountableClosedRange` so that the following would be valid code:

```
var range = 5...10 // Infers the type of range to be CountableClosedRange
range = 8          // Interprets the integer literal as a CountableClosedRange
```

So I created an extension to add the protocol conformance:

```
extension CountableClosedRange: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {

    public init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self = value...value
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this code does not compile. The line `self = value...value` throws the following error:

> `Cannot assign value of type 'CountableClosedRange<IntegerLiteralType>' (aka 'CountableClosedRange<Int>') to type 'CountableClosedRange<_>'`

---

**The problem seems to be the generic nature of `CountableClosedRange`:** It's defined as

```
struct CountableClosedRange<Bound> : RandomAccessCollection where Bound : Comparable, Bound : _Strideable, Bound.Stride : SignedInteger
```

Inside my extension the generic type `Bound` is not specified whereas `IntegerLiteralType` *is* specified (it's an `Int`). So I tried to specify `Bound` like this:

```
extension CountableClosedRange: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where Bound == Int { ... }
```

but then I got another compiler error:

> `Extension of type 'CountableClosedRange' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause`

---

#### Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I think you can't before https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md is implemented, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584237/swift-extension-on-generic-struct-based-on-properties-of-type-t for a similar issue.